# Collection View Cells not showing - none of delegate methods being called [update: collection view is nil??]

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

[update - collection view is nil for some reason...]

None of the collection view delegate methods (cellforitemat, numberofitemsinsection, sizeforitem etc) are being called at all for some reason. I have set the datasource and delegate. I've tried it in interface builder and in code in view did load. Am I missing something??

in the .h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *workoutList;
```

in the .m (workoutlist.count is 3 on print statement in VDL but not run elsewhere):

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

self.workoutCV.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.workoutCV.delegate = self;
self.workoutCV.dataSource = self;

NSLog(@"here %lu", (unsigned long)self.workoutList.count);


}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSLog(@"and here %lu", (unsigned long)self.workoutList.count);
return self.workoutList.count;

}

- (nonnull __kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString * const cellId = @"HomeCell";

HomeMenuCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;

}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(collectionView.frame) / self.workoutList.count);

}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

return 0;

}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {

return 0;

}
```

I am segue from a different Viewcontroller (HomeController) to get to this new controller. This is the code from the .m of the HomeController:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ViewController *nextVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];

nextVC.workoutList = @[@"Squats", @"Stiff Leg DL", @"Abs"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:true];

}
```

It pushes the nextVC fine and print statements run but no cells show up and no print statements run from any of the collection view delegate methods

Comment: Did you connect `workoutCV`?

Comment: yes, triple checked. and checked that there are no warnings/ issues with the connection @Willeke

Comment: `ViewController *nextVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];` doesn't alloc/init a UIViewController with its potential IB stuff (storyboard/xib). "I am segue from a different Viewcontroller (HomeController) to get to this new controller. " You are not using a `UIStoryboardSegue`, you are doing it manually and the "old way". If `workoutCV` is an IBOulet, that's normal it's nil then.